# Kafka Streams KTable join Tombstone

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, tombstone

The problem i am facing is we have joins and have multiple logical ways to product a tombstone for deleting a record in the KTable.

Is it possible to determine of if a tombstone was a result of ktable join and not not an explicit tombstone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of differentiating the tombstones i.e. one occurring as part of the `ktable join` and another one sent as an `explicit tombstone` is to set an extra header attribute in the `explicit tombstone` message and the consumer can then read those header to determine the source of tombstone.